# Laravel Application to Phar

Tags: php, laravel, phar

I have a laravel project. I'm deploying it on an Apache server by copying files to the server. Is there an alternative using phar that works like jar files?

Comment: If you want to pack an app in a .phar only to deploy it, then you're not up to date with latest practices. Why not a simple `git pull` on the server?

Comment: @N.B. I use ant to build my application on a Jenkins server. I can't just run `git pull` command on server.

Comment: You could use ant to package your application in .phar file and deploy it but it's good practice to then extract the file on the server so you might as well zip it instead. Don't leave it as phar because a) the webserver needs an unpackaged index file to work and b) there's a lot of overhead in extracting the archive which will be happening on each and every request.

Comment: I agree with @apokryfos, if it's ease of deploy you want you may need to consider a proper deploy tool, like capistrano. Ant is supposed to be a build and not a deploy, you kind of stretching it

Comment: @Magus I'm not deploying using ant. I built the application using ant and figuring out ideas on deploying it. If you could suggest some, will be a help. Thanks.

Comment: @MunavirChavody will reply in an answer because it got too long

Comment: "there's a lot of overhead" - this is wrong. `.phar` files can be uncompressed, and `.phar` files get cached by php. I benchmarked that a while ago: https://cweiske.de/tagebuch/php-phar-files.htm#benchmark

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be for you to rsync the files to the server. One a bit more complex but worked out great was using capistrano on the desired servers, the deploy script from jenkins would upload the build file to s3 and ssh into the server and run

```
bundle exec cap deploy
```

on the desired servers.

This way would make the servers deploy on themselves, in the case I used it, the capistrano on the machines did the build and deploy using git archive, but you could split your build step and deploy step.

Basically, you would have a private s3 bucket to upload your builds, they would always be named application-latest.zip

Your jenkins server would always build, upload and trigger the deploy

Your application servers would have a capistrano download the zip, unzip it and 'deploy'

Why am I mentioning capistrano so much? Because it relieves you from a lot of the deploy struggles, exemple:
- it will do the mentioned steps on a folder called application-timestamp
- this folder is kept alongside other folders containing your previous deploys
- there is a symlink called release that points to your latest deployment
- once capistrano finishes your steps, it changes the symlink to point to your fresh deployed folder

Benefits from this approach and tech choices:

- you can choose to keep 'x' last deployments, that let's you rollback deploys instantly because that is just a symlink change from your current deployment to your current-1 deployment
- that also controls how much disk space your assets take by cleaning up the oldest folders, if you chose to keep 5 deployments for rollback, when you deploy for the sixth time, the oldest folder is removed
- it prevents you from having the white screen of death that is caused when nginx/apache/php can't access the file that is currently being updated by the deploy script
- it lets you create an image of this machine, let's say on aws, and put it on a autoscale group, and once this machine is started, it updates itself by downloading the latest zip from s3 without having jenkins get in the way, you will just have to setup the autoscale init script to trigger the deploy on whatever provider you chose
- you have a very clear boundary between build and deploy

hope that helps!